# Laravel validation 'different' fails when other attribute is null

Tags: validation, laravel-5.6

Hello I'm having troubles with the [different](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-different) validation.

I have 2 variables that can be null. What I want to achieve is whenever the variable is present, force it to have exactly 5 digits and not to have the same value.

These are the rules that I've set:

```
'zip_departure' => 'nullable|digits:5',
'zip_arrival' => 'nullable|different:zip_departure|digits:5',
```

The problem is when I set `zip_departure` as `null` it throws up a validation error saying both parameters cannot have the same value. But if I `dd()` both variables they have:

```
'zip_departure': null
'zip_arrival': '28100'
```

What am I missing here?

I'm using `Laravel 5.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.6 the validator explicitly checks whether the other value is not null.

```php
public function validateDifferent($attribute, $value, $parameters) 
{ 
    $this->requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'different'); 

    foreach ($parameters as $parameter) { 
        $other = Arr::get($this->data, $parameter); 

        if (is_null($other) || $value === $other) { 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
}
```

*framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php:432*

That's why `different:var2` works but `different:var1` doesn't.

---

As of Lravel 5.8 and higher this is [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/af12e5ac232a5754a4106c0f0d888485ef6c25b6)

Comment: I'm glad they fixed this, I don't think it made sense the previous behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
'zip_departure' => 'bail|nullable|digits:5',
'zip_arrival' => 'bail|nullable|required_with:zip_departure|different:zip_departure|digits:5',
```

bail is for : Stop running validation rules after the first validation failure

[Laravel Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-bail)

required_with is for: The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

[Laravel Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-with)

Hope this helps...